# Canny edge detection in emgu loses edges

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator, emgucv

I'm programming in C# and I use EmguCV (3.1). I use Canny edge detector from CvInvoke class. My problem is this algorithm do not find some edges. My OpenCL = true. Here is my problem:

The input image:
[image: Rectangles]

And the result:
[image: Edges]

As you see, rectangles that are not rotated, miss their top edges. My questions are:

1- Is it normal?
2- In case of **NO** how can I fix it?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = true;

Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

Image<Gray, byte> im = new Image<Gray, byte>(bm);
UMat u = im.ToUMat();            

CvInvoke.Canny(u, u, 150, 50);

pictureBox1.Image = u.Bitmap;
```

Comment: No it's not suppose to happen but where is your code?

Comment: I find that when I use OpenCL this problem appears.